# xslt transformation and limiting

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I have an XML like this

```
<Ozellik isim="Renk-Beden">STANDART STD</Ozellik>
<Ozellik isim="Grup">ADMIN</Ozellik>
<Ozellik isim="Amac">DENEME</Ozellik>
<Ozellik isim="BlaBla">BLABLA</Ozellik>
```

and want to convert it to this and limit to three elements. If there is more than 3 records, take the first three of them

```
<property1 name="Renk-Beden">STANDART STD</property1>
<property2 name="Grup">ADMIN</property2>
<property3 name="Amac">DENEME</property3>
```

I tried many xslt codes but could not be able to transform it to desired output. Thanks for your help.

My last attempt which was successful is:

```
<xsl:template name="loop">
    <xsl:param name="pCount"/>
    <xsl:param name="pValue"/>
    <xsl:param name="pAtt"/>
    <xsl:element name="property{$pCount}">
    <xsl:attribute name="name">
      <xsl:value-of select="$pAtt" />
    </xsl:attribute>
      <xsl:value-of select="$pValue" />
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Ozellik">
    <xsl:param name="pCount" select="0"/>
    <xsl:for-each select="catalog/cd">
      <xsl:call-template name="loop">
       <xsl:with-param name="pCount" select="position()" />
       <xsl:with-param name="pValue" select="." />
       <xsl:with-param name="pAtt" select="@isim" />
       </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>
```

Comment: `I tried many xslt codes`, could you please post your last attempt ?

Comment: i added my last attempt

Comment: why do you select `catalog/cd`, there is no element `catalog` or `cd` from sample input you gave

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="(//Ozellik)[position() &lt; 4]"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Ozellik">
  <xsl:element name="property{position()}">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
  </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Ozellik/@isim">
  <xsl:attribute name="name">
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
  </xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: thank you this works and below answer works too :)
which one should mark ?

Answer (score 0):

To fix your last attempt. Here is what you need to do.

Remove the `for-each` element

```
<xsl:for-each select="catalog/cd">
   <!-- existing inner elements -->
</xsl:for-each>
```

and replace it with `if` element.

```
<xsl:if test="position() &lt; 4">
   <!-- existing inner elements -->
</xsl:if>
```

Your "Ozellik" template would look like this.

```
<xsl:template match="Ozellik">
  <xsl:param name="pCount" select="0"/>
  <xsl:if test="position() &lt; 4">
    <xsl:call-template name="loop">
      <xsl:with-param name="pCount" select="position()" />
      <xsl:with-param name="pValue" select="." />
      <xsl:with-param name="pAtt" select="@isim" />
    </xsl:call-template>
  </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```